# systemctl service can't restart on reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemctl

I have created a service for `systemctl` which works perfectly but whenever I reboot the server it can't auto-restart itself.

The code for the service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service Description
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=project_path
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/wrappers/bundle exec /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rake QUEUE=* resque:work
```

Path for the service is

> /lib/systemd/system/worker.service

Comment: Did you properly enable the service?

Comment: I have start the service by command systemctl start service_name

Comment: But did you enable it via `systemctl enable service_name`? Else it would only be enabled during the current session.

Comment: I'm running the command then I'm getting this error:
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.

Comment: Then you might add them :)

Comment: Got it! thank you very much. :) :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service you created needs to be enabled, not only by starting it, but by letting systemd know, that it exists. That can be done by using the command `systemctl enable worker.service`.

You might need to add some values to the config for getting the service to run properly, but without enabling the service it can't be triggered after a restart automatically.